# Push into the first object of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to push an object of object into the first object of an array.
Here is my code:

```
const titles = {
  name: 'Not 1',
  name2: 'Not 2',
};

const array = [{ type: 'type', titles: [] }];
let e;
for (const name in titles) {
  e = titles[name];
}
array.push({ name: e });
```

This is the result i get :

```
[
  { 
    "type": "type", 
    "titles": [] 
  }, 
  { "name": "Not 2" }
]
```

This is the result i want :

```
[
  { 
    "type": "type", 
    "titles": [
      { "name": "Not 1" },
      { "name": "Not 2" }
    ] 
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the object and using push push the other object in the array

```js
const titles = {
  name: 'Not 1',
  name2: 'Not 2',
};

const array = [{
  type: 'type',
  titles: []
}, {
  type: 'type',
  titles: []
}];
let e;
for (const name in titles) {
  e = titles[name];
  array.forEach(x => x.titles.push({
    name: e
  }))

}

console.log(array)
```

Comment: it worked for me, thank you. but i want the names to be pushed into different objects inside the array titles

Comment: Thank you for your help, i kind of found a way

Answer (score 0):

Just select the correct array element and push to the inner array of it.

```
const titles = {
  name: 'Not 1',
  name2: 'Not 2',
};

const array = [{ type: 'type', titles: [] }];

Object.keys(titles).forEach((key) => {
    array[0].titles.push({name: titles[key]})

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just `push()` values to `array[0].titles`

```js
const titles = {
  name: 'Not 1',
  name2: 'Not 2',
};

const array = [{ type: 'type', titles: [] }];
for (const name in titles) {
  array[0].titles.push(titles[name])
}
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.entires` with `Array.from` to form an array of separate object titles and then set your `titles` property equal to the new array:

```js
const titles = {
  name: 'Not 1',
  name2: 'Not 2',
};

const array = [{ type: 'type', titles: [] }];
array[0].titles = Array.from(Object.values(titles), v => ({"names":v}));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to push to an array of items. Use `map` and `Object.entries`

```js
const titles = {
  name: 'Not 1',
  name2: 'Not 2',
};

const array = [{
  type: 'type',
  titles: []
}, {
  type: 'type2',
  titles: []
}];

// re-build the titles before insert
const newTitles = Object.entries(titles).map(([first, second]) => ({[first]: second}))

// Insert for an array of items
const rs = array.map(({titles, ...rest}) => ({...rest, titles: newTitles}))

console.log(rs)
```